# AngularJS remove attribute containing expression not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have a directive with an attribute which I read, apply some logic (for this example console log), then remove the attribute from the HTML (valid HTML, cleanliness and accessibility). This works when the attribute value is a string, but does not remove the attribute if the value is an expression.

Pseudo code:

**index.htm**

```
Working: <my-directive foo="123"></my-directive>
Not working: <my-directive foo="{{myExpressionValue}}"></my-directive>
```

**directive.js**

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
  return {
    template:"<div>Hello World</div>",

    compile: function(element, attributes){
      // Do whatever with attribute
      console.log(attributes.foo);
      // Now remove the attribute
      element.removeAttr('foo');
    }
  };
});
```

**output**

```
Working: <div>Hello World</div>
Not working: <div foo="123">Hello World<div>
```

==========================================================

I'd like both directives to strip out the 'foo' attribute. Post link doesn't work. Assume the expression is evaluated somewhere after the directive...?

Thanks!

Comment: To be expression to be evaluated use `ng-attr-foo="{{myExpressionValue}}"`

Comment: Using 'ng-attr-foo' still creates the 'foo' attribute on the div. Currently using 'data-foo', which passes 'foo' to the directive -- but this is not the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: "<div>Hello World</div>",
    compile: function(tElement, tAttr) {
      tAttr.$set('foo', null);
    }
  }
})
```

working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/aq7ZYo8izcjDDLPUsLjZ?p=preview

[image: Now both div do not contain the Foo attr]